# Is there a way of using both the 7inch touchscreen and a hdmi tv as a dual screen for the pi

Tags: hdmi

Preferably I would like to not have to use more add on kit but will take any ideas.

Comment: Not the way you imagine, but as an alternative you can use VNC to connect to Pi virtual remote desktop session from another Pi which might have just 7" display.

Comment: Does it have to be 7"? Smaller SPI screens are [known](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59124/raspberry-pi-dual-screen) to work in parallel with HDMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately not. The RPi's hardware does not allow for multiple screen use, and honestly the CPU probably couldn't handle a dual display anyway.